# Detect Key Press on Windows Without Window Focus

Tags: c, windows, keyboard-events

I've been searching online but all the top results on Google only lead me to Java. This is frustrating.

What I want to do is: make a program that listens to keyboard events, without being the active program. It has to work on at least windows 7, using C.

For example lets say I have myprogram.exe and other.exe. I want to be able to run both of them simultaneously, and have focus on other.exe, then press keys, and have myprogram.exe which runs on the side display which keys I pressed and log them.

If somebody has a link to a guide or information that explains what I should use to make this, that would be grand. If you can write up an explanation yourself that would be even better, but I don't mind going through documentations as long as they're relevant.

I've written games in C that listen to input from the active window, but I'm not sure how to poll events when the window isn't focused.

Comment: You want a keylogger, which is typically implemented using window hooks.

Comment: You need a global hook. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#wh_keyboardhook and an example here: http://ntcoder.com/bab/2007/06/12/wh_keyboard_ll/

Comment: is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268(v=vs.85).aspx) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect 'key press' events occurred in other processes, you should implement `Global Hook`. You can define a callback function for keyboard input events using [SetWindowsHookEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx).

Note that the callback function must be in a DLL in order to make it **Global Hook**.

So your myprogram.exe should link a dll implementing the hook. Then myprogram.exe would be able to detect any keyboard events on Windows.

Following is a good example with an explanation.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks

Comment: thanks everybody. all helpful